# Check if timestamp is in separate DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, sorting

I have a DataFrame with a large amount of datetime stamps in it - called `df`:

```
    Time                Charge  PV      Energy
1   27/06/2021 04:45    NaN     1.5     1.8
2   28/06/2021 04:46    NaN     1.7     1.5
3   21/07/2021 04:47    NaN     2.5     3.1
4   29/07/2021 04:48    NaN     1.9     2.1
5   05/08/2021 04:49    NaN     1.4     1.1
```

I want to add a column that checks if the date is within a separate data frame (to see if they day is a holiday). This is the DataFrame containing the holidays (called `df_hols`)

```
    Date        Holiday
0   2021-05-29  1
1   2021-07-21  1
2   2021-08-22  1
3   2021-08-23  1
4   2021-08-30  1
5   2021-08-30  1
6   2021-09-09  1
7   2021-09-19  1
```

I am currently using:

```py
for date in df_hols['Date']:
    df['Holiday'] = np.where(df['Time'].dt.date == date, True, False)
```

and this works but is very slow.

I have tried

```py
df['Holiday'] = np.where(df['Time'].dt.date.isin(df_hols['Date']), True, False)
```

But this returned all `False`.

Comment: Please check if `dtypes` are same in both dataframes.

Comment: They are both `datetime.date`. To be precise, both `df['Time'].dt.date` and `df_hols['Date']` are `datetime.date`

Answer (score 2):

You could get the series of of the holidays, and use `isin` on the dates extracted from the Time column to check inclusion:

```
df['Holiday'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.date.astype(str)
                   .isin(df_hols['Date'])
                 )
```

output:

```
               Time  Charge   PV  Energy  Holiday
1  27/06/2021 04:45     NaN  1.5     1.8    False
2  28/06/2021 04:46     NaN  1.7     1.5    False
3  21/07/2021 04:47     NaN  2.5     3.1     True
4  29/07/2021 04:48     NaN  1.9     2.1    False
5  05/08/2021 04:49     NaN  1.4     1.1    False
```